# Getting ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT (not caused by other extensions) when connecting to Dropbox API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm new to developing a Chrome extension.

I'm developing an extension where I try to connect to Dropbox API.
I get no errors in the Chrome extension manager or in the console, but after authorizing the access to Dropbox, when it tries to access my redirect URI, I get ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT, This page is being blocked by Chrome/Microsoft Edge.

I think the values needed to connect to Dropbox are correct, I print them as logs, and apparently, I give permission because it appears in Dropbox apps. but I get no info on the extension side (like the access key). I have no inline scripts in the HTML. Could it be a CSP issue?
Don't know if it is important, but forgot to say that, since the extension is local, the redirect URI is a local file as well.
So it access chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID/redirect.html (...)

Thanks in advance.

I already tried in another browser with no other extensions, as well as in a new Chrome profile, and still the same result, so I'm pretty confident it isn't a conflict with another extension.

EDIT:
I messed around with it, and now i get the same error, but if i press reload page it does what is supposed to and saves my access token for Dropbox. I noticed that if i press F5 it doesnt work as well, i need to click the reload button that the error page shows. Any way to solve it? Or maybe to reload the page automatically?

Comment: Add "redirect.html" to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. I already have that in my manifest, still get the error.
It says "extension_id is blocked", no errors anywhere, so it is hard to find the fix

Comment: You also need to reload the extension after editing. Also, if `extension_id` is what it literally says, there's a mistake in your code and you need to use chrome.runtime.getURL instead.

Comment: i know i need to reload after editing. In the message it has my extension actual id, instead of "extension_id", just wrote that here so it was easier to understand

Comment: I messed around with it, and now i get the same error, but if i press reload page it does what is supposed to and saves my access token for Dropbox. Any way to solve it? Or maybe to reload the page automatically?